# unit test for insertion method using mockito

Tags: java, mysql, unit-testing, mockito, dao

I have a problem in  the unit test of the insertion method,although i use a mock object ,the data is inserted to the database ,what's wrong in this please ?

here's the source code of the method

```
public void InsertPersonalData(PersonalData personaldata) throws SQLException, DAOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        try {
            PreparedStatement psmt = MysqlConnection.getPreparedStatement("INSERT INTO personal_data values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
            psmt.setString(1, personaldata.getiD());
            psmt.setString(2, personaldata.getPatientName());
            psmt.setString(3, personaldata.getBirthDate());
            psmt.setString(4, personaldata.getPlaceOfBirth());
            psmt.setString(5, personaldata.getGender());
            psmt.setString(6, personaldata.getNationality());
            psmt.setString(7, personaldata.getCurrentAddress());
            psmt.setString(8, personaldata.getCityAddress());
            psmt.setString(9, personaldata.getMaritalStatus());
            psmt.setString(10, personaldata.getOffspring());
            psmt.setString(11, personaldata.getAgeOfYoungestOffspring());
            psmt.setString(12, personaldata.getWorkNature());
            psmt.setString(13, personaldata.getPhoneNumber());
            psmt.setString(14, personaldata.geteMail());

            psmt.executeUpdate();

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new DAOException(e);

        }
```

here's how i used mocking

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class PersonalDataDaoTest {

    public PersonalData newpd;

    @Mock
    Connection conn;

    @Mock
    PreparedStatement psmt;

    @InjectMocks
    PersonalDataDao newDAO = new PersonalDataDao();
```

the test code:

```
@Test
    public void HappyTestForInsert() throws SQLException, DAOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        when(conn.prepareStatement(anyString())).thenReturn(psmt);
        //ArgumentCaptor<Integer> intcaptor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(int.class);
        ArgumentCaptor<String> stringcaptor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(String.class);
        String id = "11";
        String patientName = "yara";
        String birthDate = "2001-12-5";
        String placeOfBirth = "cairo";
        String gender = "female";
        String nationality = "egyptian";
        String currentAddress = "cairo";
        String cityAddress = "cairo";
        String maritalStatus = "married";
        String offspring = "1";
        String ageOfYoungestOffspring = "2";
        String workNature = "teacher";
        String phoneNumber = "0324324234";
        String eMail = "yara@hotmail.com";

        PersonalData p = new PersonalData(id, patientName, birthDate, placeOfBirth, gender, nationality, currentAddress, cityAddress, maritalStatus, offspring, ageOfYoungestOffspring, workNature, phoneNumber, eMail);
        newDAO.InsertPersonalData(p);
        //verify(psmt, times(1)).setInt(anyInt(), intcaptor.capture());
        verify(psmt, times(14)).setString(anyInt(), stringcaptor.capture());
        Assert.assertTrue(stringcaptor.getAllValues().get(0).equals(id));
        Assert.assertTrue(stringcaptor.getAllValues().get(1).equals(patientName));
        Assert.assertTrue(stringcaptor.getAllValues().get(2).equals(birthDate));
        Assert.assertTrue(stringcaptor.getAllValues().get(3).equals(placeOfBirth));
        Assert.assertTrue(stringcaptor.getAllValues().get(4).equals(gender));
        Assert.assertTrue(stringcaptor.getAllValues().get(5).equals(nationality));
        Assert.assertTrue(stringcaptor.getAllValues().get(6).equals(currentAddress));
        Assert.assertTrue(stringcaptor.getAllValues().get(7).equals(cityAddress));
        Assert.assertTrue(stringcaptor.getAllValues().get(8).equals(maritalStatus));
        Assert.assertTrue(stringcaptor.getAllValues().get(9).equals(offspring));
        Assert.assertTrue(stringcaptor.getAllValues().get(10).equals(ageOfYoungestOffspring));
        Assert.assertTrue(stringcaptor.getAllValues().get(11).equals(workNature));
        Assert.assertTrue(stringcaptor.getAllValues().get(12).equals(phoneNumber));
        Assert.assertTrue(stringcaptor.getAllValues().get(13).equals(eMail));

    }
```

Comment: Please do not add code segments as image, but include the actual code in your post.

Comment: i have edited it :)

Comment: The insert happens in the method `InsertPersonalData`. Based on the setup of your test, you are not mocking the `PersonalDataDAO` but testing it, hence the insert is executed.

Comment: but the query in the DAO class so i used mocking , what should i do ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to verify the usage of the prepared statement in your test. The way your code is set up this will not work, as the instance of the `PreparedStatement` is created within the method you are testing: `InsertPersonalData`.

But you can modify your code so that it becomes testable. The first step is to move the creation of the `PreparedStatement` into a separate class, which then can be mocked in your test:

```
public class StatementProvider {
    public PreparedStatement createInsertStatementForPersonalData() {
        return PreparedStatement psmt = MysqlConnection.getPreparedStatement("INSERT INTO personal_data values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
    }
}
```

Next you update your `PersonalDataDao` to use the `StatementProvider`:

```
public class PersonalDataDao {
    private StatementProvider statementProvider;
    // Constructor and other methods ommitted
    public void InsertPersonalData(PersonalData personaldata) throws SQLException, DAOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        try {
            PreparedStatement psmt = statementProvider.createInsertStatementForPersonalData(); 
            psmt.setString(1, personaldata.getiD());
            psmt.setString(2, personaldata.getPatientName());
            psmt.setString(3, personaldata.getBirthDate());
            psmt.setString(4, personaldata.getPlaceOfBirth());
            psmt.setString(5, personaldata.getGender());
            psmt.setString(6, personaldata.getNationality());
            psmt.setString(7, personaldata.getCurrentAddress());
            psmt.setString(8, personaldata.getCityAddress());
            psmt.setString(9, personaldata.getMaritalStatus());
            psmt.setString(10, personaldata.getOffspring());
            psmt.setString(11, personaldata.getAgeOfYoungestOffspring());
            psmt.setString(12, personaldata.getWorkNature());
            psmt.setString(13, personaldata.getPhoneNumber());
            psmt.setString(14, personaldata.geteMail());

            psmt.executeUpdate();

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new DAOException(e);

        }
    } 
}
```

And then your test looks like this:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class PersonalDataDaoTest {

    @Mock
    private PreparedStatement psmt;
    @Mock
    private StatmentProvider statementProvider; 

    @InjectMocks
    private PersonalDataDao newDAO; // This is the class under test
    @Test
    public void HappyTestForInsert() throws SQLException, DAOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        when(statementProvider.createInsertStatementForPersonalData()).thenReturn(psmt);
        //ArgumentCaptor<Integer> intcaptor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(int.class);
        ArgumentCaptor<String> stringcaptor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(String.class);
        String id = "11";
        String patientName = "yara";
        String birthDate = "2001-12-5";
        String placeOfBirth = "cairo";
        String gender = "female";
        String nationality = "egyptian";
        String currentAddress = "cairo";
        String cityAddress = "cairo";
        String maritalStatus = "married";
        String offspring = "1";
        String ageOfYoungestOffspring = "2";
        String workNature = "teacher";
        String phoneNumber = "0324324234";
        String eMail = "yara@hotmail.com";

        PersonalData p = new PersonalData(id, patientName, birthDate, placeOfBirth, gender, nationality, currentAddress, cityAddress, maritalStatus, offspring, ageOfYoungestOffspring, workNature, phoneNumber, eMail);
        newDAO.InsertPersonalData(p);
        //verify(psmt, times(1)).setInt(anyInt(), intcaptor.capture());
        verify(psmt, times(14)).setString(anyInt(), stringcaptor.capture());
        Assert.assertTrue(stringcaptor.getAllValues().get(0).equals(id));
        Assert.assertTrue(stringcaptor.getAllValues().get(1).equals(patientName));
        Assert.assertTrue(stringcaptor.getAllValues().get(2).equals(birthDate));
        Assert.assertTrue(stringcaptor.getAllValues().get(3).equals(placeOfBirth));
        Assert.assertTrue(stringcaptor.getAllValues().get(4).equals(gender));
        Assert.assertTrue(stringcaptor.getAllValues().get(5).equals(nationality));
        Assert.assertTrue(stringcaptor.getAllValues().get(6).equals(currentAddress));
        Assert.assertTrue(stringcaptor.getAllValues().get(7).equals(cityAddress));
        Assert.assertTrue(stringcaptor.getAllValues().get(8).equals(maritalStatus));
        Assert.assertTrue(stringcaptor.getAllValues().get(9).equals(offspring));
        Assert.assertTrue(stringcaptor.getAllValues().get(10).equals(ageOfYoungestOffspring));
        Assert.assertTrue(stringcaptor.getAllValues().get(11).equals(workNature));
        Assert.assertTrue(stringcaptor.getAllValues().get(12).equals(phoneNumber));
        Assert.assertTrue(stringcaptor.getAllValues().get(13).equals(eMail));

    }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to return multiple queries in the StatementProvider class as i have multiple classes to test in the same manner?

Comment: As you are mocking the returned mock object within your test method, you can have multiple test methods returning different mocks. I would expect that your implementation for `StatementProvider` has several methods one for each kind of `PrepraredStatement`.